# set value of a field in gsp grails

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a Album domain class;

```
class Album {

    String caption
    String description
    SortedSet pictures

    static hasMany = [pictures:Picture,posts:Post]
}

class Post {

    Album album
    Picture picture
    String caption
    String content

}
```

In my gsp I am trying to set the values of respective album and picture value;

```
<label for="picture">
    <g:message code="post.picture.label" default="Picture" />
</label>
**<span id="picture" aria-labelledby="picture-label">${pictureInstance?.caption?.encodeAsHTML()}</span>**

<label for="album">
    <g:message code="post.album.label" default="Album" />
</label>
**<span id="album" aria-labelledby="album-label">${pictureInstance?.album?.encodeAsHTML()}</span>**
```

though in my browser I see right values in front of album and picture label, when I try to save the post, **it says property picture and album cannot be null**. I dont understand why is it not writing these values into the DB..

If my approach to achieve this is not right, any alternate suggestion would help a lot

Thanks..

Comment: You have two properties with the name **pictures**. One is of type SortedSet and the other is of type Picture.

Answer (score 0):

Grails has a powerful mechanism to validate the properties defined in the domain class. The constraints block can be used to define rules for the properties inside of which a closure is passed. There you can define many rules like blank, nullable, min and max size,etc. Whenever save() is called in grails it automatically calls validate method which validates over these constraints.

I think the issue with your case is by default if you don't define any rules inside constraints for properties in grails then they take default values like can't be null in your case. So you are getting cannot be null message. For this define required rules for different proprties inside constraints block in domain class

static constraints = {

picture nullable: true, blank:true;

album nullable:true

//Rules for other properties goes here

}

Comment: I cannot afford to make them null in my case. Just to give more info, those fields are generated as ;


<g:select id="album" name="album.id" from="${Album.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${postInstance?.album?.id}" class="many-to-one"/>

and similar <g:select> for picture. And this way I can infact save the instances without any exception. But I am trying to point it to respective values and hence manipulating the actual-generated code and somehow the way I am doing it is not right!!